# Angular velocity of a particle moving in 3D

Tags: vectors, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

I have a particle trajectory where particle position is available at discrete time steps with respect of (0,0,0) in 3D. Time step is 0.05 sec.  For reference, positions are shown in following image.[image: Particle Positions]

Particle velocity can be computed easily. My goal is to calculate angular velocity for each time step. Here are the different ways I have tried:

1. **Velocity vector**
   For each consecutive time step we can calculate change in direction of velocity vector. let's suppose velocity at point 1 is $\bf{v_{1}}$ and at point 2 $\bf{v_{2}}$. We can calculate change in angle by
   $$
   \theta = acos(\frac{\bf{v_{1}}.\bf{v_{2}}}{v_{1}v_{2}})
   $$
   I am using unit velocity vectors to compute this angle. Finally we can divide this by time step to acquire angular velocity.
2. **Position vector**
   We can repeat the same procedure but we can use position vector.
3. [Wikipedia Page Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity)
   I have also tried using this formula as listed at Wikipedia page:
   $$
   \omega = \frac{\bf{r} \times \bf{v}}{r^{2}}
   $$
   My confusion with this formula is the units. Is it per time step and if so do I need to multiply with 20 or not.

My issue is not with the calculation itself because I can manipulate rotation matrix and quaternion. My issue is that I do not know which vectors are useful here to calculate the angular velocity and how do I use them. Any comment or suggestion would be help full.

Comment: Perhaps this help you? https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/596622/ . From the „static“ rotation matrix you can obtain three Euler angles

Comment: @Eli Yes I have looked at that question. As I do not have continuous function it becomes complicated. Off course I can try to fit a polynomial to acquire a function f(t) to calculate TNB axis but I think that is not the way to go in this particular case.

Comment: A particle does not have angular velocity, as it occupies zero space.

Comment: What interpolation function did you use to get velocity, because finite difference is going to produce a lot of noise.

Comment: I used finite difference method. You are right that it produces a lot of noise. Now 2 years later, we ended up using a piecewise polynomial to fit the data. This also smooth the signal. We then simply do the analytical derivation to calculate the velocity.

Answer (score 0):

You have a time series $\mathbf r (n\Delta t)$ where $\Delta t = 0.05$ seconds. To apply the formula

$$\mathbf \omega = \frac {\mathbf r \times \mathbf v}{r^2}$$

at time $t=n\Delta t$ start with

$$\mathbf v(t) \approx \frac{\mathbf r(t+\Delta t) - \mathbf r(t)}{\Delta t} = 20(\mathbf r(t+\Delta t) - \mathbf r(t))$$

so

$$\mathbf \omega (t) \approx 20 \frac {\mathbf r(t) \times \mathbf r(t+\Delta t)}{r^2}$$

since $\mathbf r(t) \times \mathbf r(t)=0$. The units here are radians per second. If you want radians per time step omit the factor of $20$.

Note that this gives you the instantaneous angular velocity about the origin - the angular velocity about any other point will be different.

Comment: Thanks. I have computed it and my histogram is distributed from 1 to 4 degrees. This is not that high as I expected because I do have a lot of turns. But may be per time step is not that high.